# How to force the casing of letters in a textbox

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net-mvc

In my MVC app I have some name fields and I want to make sure that the first letter is a capital, and the rest are lower case.
No problem you may, just use this;
Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Employee.Surname, new { style = "text-transform: capitalize;" }

Well there are 2 problems with this;
1/ When you save the data you have to convert the text again. The CSS does not convert the underlying data, only what you see on the screen. 
2/ My boss decided to try out my screen for the first time, and she habitually uses capitals for this kind of form. So she want a text conversion to force the lower casing from the second letter onwards. So if she types SMITH she wants to see Smith.
I am wondering how to do this. If looks like a need a client side event for every keystroke to make this conversion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
$(function() {

    $(".field").blur(function() {
       $(this).val( $(this).val().substr(0,1).toUpperCase() + $(this).val().substr(1).toLowerCase());
    });

});
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/c5wCm/5/

Comment: +1 This is an improved version. It is not perfect but it will certainly surfice as a solution. The only problem with it is that it doesn't convert the casing until I tab to the next line.

Comment: I'm personally not a fan of form fields changing my values as I'm typing, on top of that Firefox seems to act strange when the value is longer than the visible area of the input, showing me the start of the value as opposed to where the carot actually is.

Comment: Sounds reasonable but my boss does not understand that kind of argument!

Answer (score -2):

Try this javascript:

Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Employee.Surname, new { @onkeypress = "caseL(this, event);" }

or

Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Employee.Surname, new { @onkeypress = "caseS(this);" }

```
function caseL(obj, evt) {
    /*
    A lazy word capitaliser.
    e.g onKeypress="caseL(this,event);"
    */
    var iLen;
    var key;
    iLen = obj.value.length;
    if (navigator.appName == 'Netscape') {
        key = evt.charCode;
        if ((key == 0) && (evt.which == 13)) {
            //Enter key so suppress
            evt.preventDefault();
        }
    } else {
        key = window.event.keyCode;
        if (key == 13) {
            //Enter key so suppress
            window.event.cancelBubble = true;
            window.event.returnValue = false;
        }
    }
    if ((iLen == 0) || (obj.value.charAt(iLen - 1) == " ") || (obj.value.charAt(iLen - 1) == "-")) {

        if ((key > 0x60) && (key < 0x7B)) {
            if (navigator.appName == 'Netscape') {
                key = key - 0x20;
                var newEvent = document.createEvent("KeyEvents")
                newEvent.initKeyEvent("keypress", true, true, document.defaultView, evt.ctrlKey, evt.altKey, evt.shiftKey, evt.metaKey, 0, String.fromCharCode(key).charCodeAt(0))
                evt.preventDefault()
                evt.target.dispatchEvent(newEvent)
            } else {
                window.event.keyCode = key - 0x20;
            }
        }
    }
}


function caseS(obj){
/* 
A strict word capitaliser.
e.g onKeypress="caseS(this);"
*/
var iLen;
iLen=obj.value.length;
key = window.event.keyCode;
if((iLen>0)&&(obj.value.charAt(iLen-1)!=" ")&&(obj.value.charAt(iLen-1)!="-")){
    if ((key > 0x40) && (key < 0x5B))
    window.event.keyCode = key+0x20;
    return true;
}
if ((iLen==0)||(obj.value.charAt(iLen-1)==" ")||(obj.value.charAt(iLen-1)=="-")){
    if ((key > 0x60) && (key < 0x7B))
    window.event.keyCode = key-0x20;
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you for that. Well I tried your initial version and I found that the javascript method was not getting called for a key press in the first place. I am using MVC2 and IE8.

Comment: -1 for `navigator.appName == 'Netscape'`. If your going to recommend something I would recommend [`underscore.string`](https://github.com/edtsech/underscore.string)